# Curl memory buffer size too small

Tags: c, curl, libcurl

I'm trying to get some data from a certain web-based api using the `libcurl` c api.
Curl calls the api fine. However, `size_t nmemb` is too small to hold the response. Somehow it is "cut off" at 1280. Does anyone know how to solve this? Also `size_t size` is 1..

These are the functions I use:

```
int http_call(char *url) {

    CURL *curl;
    FILE *curlfile;
    CURLcode res;

    char outfilename[FILENAME_MAX] = "/usr/local/var/log/ndcurl";
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl) {

        curlfile = fopen(outfilename,"w");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_release_data);

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, fp);

        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
        fclose(curlfile);

    }

    return 0;

}
```

And the callback:

```
static size_t write_release_data(void *buffer, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp) {

    char **response_ptr =  (char**)userp;
    *response_ptr = strndup(buffer, (size_t)(size *nmemb));
    printf("The Response: %s", *response_ptr);

    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fix your callback to return the actual number of bytes written.  From [the documentation](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html)

> Pass a pointer to a function that matches the following prototype:
>   `size_t function( char *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void
>   *userdata);` This function gets called by libcurl as soon as there is data received that needs to be saved. The size of the data pointed to
>   by `ptr` is `size` multiplied with `nmemb`, it will not be zero terminated.
>   **Return the number of bytes actually taken care of.** If that amount
>   differs from the amount passed to your function, it'll signal an error
>   to the library. This will abort the transfer and return
>   `CURLE_WRITE_ERROR`.

If you return `size * nmemb`, libcurl should call your function again with the rest of the response.

Comment: it can also be noted that the callback will then be called multiple times until all data has been delivered

Comment: Ok great, it works now. One more question: I need to pass the complete response to another function. How would I do that?

Comment: You'll need to cache the response somewhere (global created with `malloc`, file on disk, etc.) and wait for curl to finish sending it to you.  You'll have to read the curl docs to find out how it signals that the transfer is complete.  Make use of the `userdata` parameter to your callback function to keep track of the state, in case you are transferring multiple URLs.